# Highlight the pre selected spinner item

Tags: android, spinner

Say I have 10 items in the spinner list.
And item number 3 is already selected. Now the thing is when user wants to change his selection, I want to give some kind of indication that this(item number 3)  which is already selected item. I want to achieve this via a Check-mark or setting some kind of background or in similar ways.

Can anybody please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I use custom adapter for this feature. Just extend it from `BaseAdapter` and inflate your views for `Spinner` and `Droppdown` control.

```
List<String> stagesValues = new ArrayList<>(stagesResults.values());
mStageSpn.setAdapter(new DropdownAdapter(mContext, stagesValues, mStageSpn));

public class DropdownAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<String> mData;
    private Spinner mStageSpn;

    public DropdownAdapter(Context context, List<String> data, Spinner stageSpn) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mData = data;
        mStageSpn = stageSpn;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, null);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(mData.get(mStageSpn.getSelectedItemPosition()));

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, null);
        if (mStageSpn.getSelectedItemPosition() == position)
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_id)).setText(mData.get(position));

        return view;
    }

}
```